# Word for when a writer uses alternate spelling and grammar to immitate a dialect

Tags: writing, dialects, dialogue, eye-dialect

What is the word for when a writer spells words of a character's dialogue differently for a character in order to express an accent or dialect? I think it starts with a 'd'.

Comment: One word for this is *eye dialect*.

Answer (score 2):

This is called [***phonetic transcription***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_transcription):

> the visual representation of speech sounds

[Wikipedia]

When I saw your description, my mind instantly went to Zora Neale Hurston's *[Their Eyes Were Watching God](http://www.cnusd.k12.ca.us/cms/lib/CA01001152/Centricity/domain/5532/language%20arts%203a/Their%20Eyes.pdf)*, which uses phonetic transcription throughout the entirety of the book.

> *“If God don’t think no mo’ ’bout ’em then Ah do, they’s
>   a lost ball in de high grass.”*

Comment: Sorry, that is not phonetic transcription. That is eye dialect, as Peter Shor points out above. By contrast, ['ðɪsɪzfə'nɛɾɨktræn'skrɪpʃɨn].